# Issues after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu-bug

I have attached an image of my laptop screen after I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 from 12.04. You will notice that all the desktop shows is 3 files. No taskbars or topbars are on the screen. When I start Ubuntu I get an "Internal Error Occurred msg" also.

Any help or advice on how to fix would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have not attached anything...

Comment: "Internal Error Occured msg" nothing more?

Comment: There is no image. We cannot help you without more info. Please reattach the image.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and tried some of the tips on reverting to open source graphics due to my old ATI driver on the 12.04.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri fglrx-modaliases
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core
```

Found these commands at this [**link**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection?action=show&redirect=X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem%3a_Need_to_purge_-fglrx).

I think there was a message about `fglrx-modaliases` no longer being supported or missing but it still worked for me. Had to reboot after doing this.

I was able to get the terminal up from a right click option on the desktop.

Hope that helps.